# Как учесть совокупность всех сумм любых двух элементов списка?

Tags: python

Имеется совокупность переменных a-e. При условии, что сумма любых двух элементов из списка меньше заданной величины, выполняется операция. Как прописать проверку этих сумм, не прибегая к занудному перечислению типа:

```
if a + b < x or \
    a + c < x or \:
    print('...')
```

Comment: Вы принципиально не используете списки?

Answer (score 3):

Если сумма двух максимальных элементов списка меньше заданной величины, то и сумма любых двух элементов этого списка меньше той же заданной величины. Итого, получаете два максимальных элемента, и считаете их сумму.

```
l = [a, b, c, d, e]
m1 = max(l)
l.remove(m1)
m2 = max(l)
if m1 + m2 < x:
    pass
```

Comment: `items = [a, b, c, d, e]; if sum(heapq.nlargest(2, items)) < x: ..` -- это может быть достаточно эффективно для большого числа элементов¶ Для 5 элементов, можно даже квадратичное решение использовать: `all(items[i] + items[j] < x for i in range(len(items)) for j in range(i+1, len(items)))` или `all(sum(terms) < x for terms in itertools.combinations(items, 2))`

Answer (score 2):

Пример:

```
In [9]: from itertools import combinations

In [10]: lst = [3, 0, 1, 2, 4]

In [11]: for tup in combinations(lst, 2):
    ...:     print(tup, sum(tup))
    ...:
(3, 0) 3
(3, 1) 4
(3, 2) 5
(3, 4) 7
(0, 1) 1
(0, 2) 2
(0, 4) 4
(1, 2) 3
(1, 4) 5
(2, 4) 6
```